# Cloning a sharepoint rolegroup

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint

I'd like to write a C# application to clone a SharePoint MOSS2007 role group (and its permissions) in however don't have a starting point.

MOSS2007 seems quite under-documented (in terms of development) and despite googling the problem quite extensively still don't have any idea what to start trying. I was hoping somebody here had done something similar and/or knew the SharePoint library enough to provide a good reference point.

I sincerely apologise for the basic question and also not providing more information - if I had anything else I would!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when 'cloning' a SharePoint security group its first of all not about the group itself but about the permissions.

These permissions are stored as roleassignments to a SPWeb object. First you must find the group that you want to clone by doing:

```
SPGroup group = spWeb.Groups["name group"];
```

Then you must use this retrieved group to get the roleassignments on the SPWeb object.

```
SPRoleAssignment ass = spWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(group2);
```

Then you must simply create a new SPGroup and add the group to the roleassignment and the roleassignment to the web object:

```
spWeb.SiteGroups.Add(groupName, user, user, groupDescription);
SPGroup newGroup = spWeb.SiteGroups[groupName];
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(newGroup);

//add role to web
spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
spWeb.Update();
```

After this you should have a new group with the same permissions as the original group.

If you're not doing the above in a sharepoint feature or something you can do it from a console application. Just create a console application in VS and fill it with something like this:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using Microsoft.SharePoint;   
namespace ConsoleApplication 
{     
class Program     
{         
static void Main(string[] args)         
{             
    using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://yoururl"))            
    {                 
          using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.RootWeb)   
          {                     
            //perform the code to clone the group here
          }          
    }                  
 }    
 } 
}
```

Comment: How does this authenticate? I'm assuming that you simply run it on the ISS server?

Comment: what are you going to do with the group object? The above example is only on how to clone the group, not on how to access SharePoint. You can simply create a console application which accesses your sharepoint environment.

Comment: Sorry, it appears I'm well out of my depth. What should I read up on to learn about how to do that?

Comment: hehe np :) I will add this to my original answer, give me a sec ;)

Comment: Thank-you so very much. What resources or books would you recommend for learning this (at the core) along with other things that can be done?

Comment: Oh, permissions also, using the above - who will this authenticate as? I'm assuming it must be run from an admin account on the IIS server?

Comment: it indeed uses the account from which you run it and you need enough permission to do so. Make sure that the account has full control in the SharePoint environment, so an admin account would probably be fine...

Comment: and to answer your question concerning learning sharepoint; read blogposts, ask questions and just give it a try. Thats always the best method.

Comment: Sorry for the bombardment of questions (every answer has been very much appreciated) - but in my reading I understand the best way to do t his remotely (not on the target machine) is via web services? How would I approach the problem to accomplish the task that way?

Comment: hehe, this is almost a different question but i'll answer it below

Comment: This creates the group, but doesn't appear to write the permissions back? We never use this variable: SPRoleAssignment ass = spWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(group2);

Comment: it's been about a year ago since you asked your question but you are correct. I guess you need to get the roledefinition out of your original group/roleassignment. You can probably do it by using: ass.RoleDefinitionBindings. After that you can import it in your new roleassignment by doing roleAssignment.ImportRoleDefinitionBindings

Answer (score 1):

When you want to edit, change or add groups remotely you can indeed use a webservice. The webservice you'll need it the usergroup.asmx. You can find the methods of this webservice by simply calling it in SharePoint.

So browse: `http://MySharePointSite/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx`

This will give you a list of all the available methods of the service. Connecting to the webservice from an application can be done by:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458094.aspx

and this tells you how to interact with the usergroup webservice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412944.aspx